# How to test read/write filesystem permissions of directory Oracle?

Tags: oracle, permissions, directory

Say you create a directory like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY 
EXT_DATA_FILES AS 
'/data/ext_data_files';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SYS.EXT_DATA_FILES TO MYAPPUSER;
```

I want to know if Oracle is capable of reading and writing files into that path. How could I test it?

That would help me a lot when creating external tables to avoid obscure error messages not really related to permissions error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `UTL_FILE` package.  For example, this will verify that you can create a new file named `some_new_file_name.txt` in the directory and write data to it

```
DECLARE
  l_file utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
  l_file := utl_file.fopen( 'EXT_DATA_FILES', 'some_new_file_name.txt', 'W' );
  utl_file.put_line( l_file, 'Here is some text' );
  utl_file.fclose( l_file );
END;
```

This will verify that a file named `existing_file_name.txt` exists and is readable

```
DECLARE
  l_exists     boolean;
  l_size       integer;
  l_block_size integer;
BEGIN
  utl_file.fgetattr( 'EXT_DATA_FILES', 
                     'existing_file_name.txt', 
                     l_exists, 
                     l_size, 
                     l_block_size );
   if( l_exists )
   then
     dbms_output.put_line( 'The file exists and has a size of ' || l_size );
   else
     dbms_output.put_line( 'The file does not exist or is not visible to Oracle' );
   end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You (or an admin) will have to login as oracle on the box to test that.

Or...just login as root and check the permissions on the directory.  oracle's primary group at our shop is "oinstall".  If the directory is not owned by oracle, you should make the group of the directory be oinstall.

I had a headache recently on getting permissions right in regards to external tables that I detailed here: [sqlplus error on select from external table: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066191/sqlplus-error-on-select-from-external-table-ora-29913-error-in-executing-odcie)

Comment: -1; the OP is asking how to check _from Oracle_ not the OS that everything is fine.

Comment: @Ben - _from Oracle_ is not specifically defined here.  "I want to know if Oracle is capable of reading and writing files into that path" would very much be dependent on if the oracle user would be able to access the files on the OS, wouldn't it?