# script that pulls data from a txt file in the where clause

Tags: oracle, variables, parameters, text-files, toad

I am trying to write an sql script in **toad for oracle version 9.5** that when run will allow the user to select data from a txt file from the c drive where the parameters / variables are entered. The version of oracle is 10g

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an [Oracle external directory](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i.php) is perfect for the job.  Keep in mind this approach is fraught with difficulties if this is a text file that users can write to.  Users will do a hundred things you never believed possible that will cause errors and [more](http://xkcd.com/327/).

From the article:

Create a directory

grant read, write on directory data_dir to your_user;

Create an external table

```
CREATE TABLE test_ext (
  test_code      VARCHAR2(5),
  test_name      VARCHAR2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      test_code      CHAR(5),
      test_name      CHAR(50)
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('test1.txt','test2.txt')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

and then read from the table

```
SELECT *
    FROM   test_ext
    ORDER BY test_name;
```

Edit: you can still do this with directories that are not located on the database server but more work is required and this represents even more of a risk to database security and data quality.
This approach does not scale either.  Do you intend to add a new directory every time a new user is added?

Steps to allow Oracle to access files located on another machine (assuming Windows operating system)

- create a windows or domain user who will have read file permissions on every directory that you wish to access
- on the database server run services.msc and change the user that the Oracle database service runs on to the your new domain user.  Add this user to the local group called ORA_DBA on the database server
- restart the database for the changes to take effect
- create a directory in the database using a path like //clientPc/sharedFolder
- grant read permissions to your database user
- on the client machine grant read to the domain user on that folder
- verify connectivity [by using UTLFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806677/how-to-test-read-write-filesystem-permissions-of-directory-oracle) to read a sample file on the client pc

Comment: This works seamless when the user has sys privilege and the text file reside on the same machine as the server.
However, how will this work when the text file resides external or on the same server and the user is imputting the data from a regular pc with a logon without sys privilege.
The following error is encountered:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04063: unable to open log file ADMINS_26597.log
 OS error No such file or directory
ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 19

Comment: You need to add those criteria to your question.

Comment: I understand.  But can you assist with this one. The oracle 10g database is installed on a linux 5.5 machine and the sql scripts are ran from Toad in xp machine to create the table. are there any thing specific that the DBA must do in the creation and granting access  and sharing of the directory/folder