# Pull Oracle data From Excel File

Tags: excel, oracle

So I have a lot of rows taken up by excel. I have 10,000 rows or so taken up by data and I am working with 10,000 or different IDs. Is there a way to query off an oracle database just 1 time by capturing the entire ID column as a group and including the group in the WHERE query instead of looping the 10,000 assets and query the database 10,000 times?

Sorry for not providing code. I really have not attempted this because I dont know if a solution exists.

Comment: Just import the excel sheet into a temporary table.  There are many ways to do this and 10,000 rows is not that much.

Comment: @kevinsky that sounds good! Would you happen to have example code :P? I have never dealt with temp tables. Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like what you are asking can be accomplished in a two step process.  First, by creating SELECT-FROM-DUAL queries for the relevant IDs, and second, inputting those queries into your main query and joining against them to limit to only the returns you need.

**For the first step, use Excel to create SELECT-FROM-DUAL subqueries.**
If your ID column starts in cell A2, copy the following formula into an empty cell on the same row and drag it down the column until all rows with an ID also have the formula.  Alter the references to cell A2 and A3 if your IDs don't start in cell A2.

```
="SELECT "&A2&" AS id FROM DUAL"&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A3)), " UNION ALL", "")
```

Ultimately, what we want is a block of SELECT-FROM-DUAL statements that look like the below.  Note that the last statement will not end in "UNION ALL", but all other statements should.
| IDs   | Formula                               |
|-----  |------------------------------------   |
| 1     | SELECT 1 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL    |
| 2     | SELECT 2 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL    |
| 3     | SELECT 3 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL    |
| 4     | SELECT 4 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL    |
| 5     | SELECT 5 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL    |
| 6     | SELECT 6 AS id FROM DUAL              |

**For the second step, add all the SELECT-FROM-DUAL statements to your main query and then add an appropriate JOIN condition.**

```sql
SELECT
            *

FROM        table_you_need tyn
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT 1 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS id FROM DUAL
) your_ids yi
ON          tyn.id = yi.id
;
```

If you had a shorter list of IDs you could use a similar strategy to create an ID list for a `WHERE ids IN (<list_of_numbers>)` clause, but the IN list is typically limited to 100 items, and consequently would not work for your current question.

Comment: Very Interesting! But would this hold for 100k records too? Seems very computationally intensive

Comment: It will take a little time to transfer the query into the database, but of course if you are wanting to process those 10K or 100K of IDs via the database you'll have initial load time no matter what approach you take.  Personally I haven't found it to take very long even for large datasets.  And more importantly, since the data is being loaded just one time at the start of the query it avoids any context switching during the query which is where many performance problems arise.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data from Excel using Toad or [SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/how-to-import-from-excel-to-a-new-oracle-table-with-sql-developer/).  You need to create a table first in the database.

You can read the data [directly with external tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29186459/851930) if you save the excel file as a CSV file to a folder on the database server that the database can access.

You can read files as Excel (xls or xlsx format) using a [PL/SQL library](https://chrisonoracle.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/read-excel-file-in-plsql-using-java-in-the-db/).

There are probably a few other ways I haven't thought of as well. This is a very [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+excel).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I should have specified I was looking for a VBA based answer... my bad.